# Dictionary of Mishnaic Hebrew (aside from Jastrow)

Tags: hebrew, mishna, tannaim, dictionary

Can anyone recommend a dictionary of Mishnaic Hebrew? Jastrow is serviceable, but not great. I am looking for a better option.

Some suggestions would be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: https://www.eichlers.com/aramaic-hebrew-english-dictionary-of-babylonian-talmud-hardcover.html?gclid=Cj0KCQiA2sqOBhCGARIsAPuPK0jvhyv3-Ghqchb_roXEonvufbytr-7P2A6nDP25fUKX00fYv_KJ77QaAuxiEALw_wcB

Comment: https://judaicaspot.com/products/talmud-gemara-dictionary-talmudo-beyado-%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%D7%95-%D7%91%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95?variant=34096643899527&currency=USD&utm_medium=product_sync&utm_source=google&utm_content=sag_organic&utm_campaign=sag_organic&utm_campaign=gs-2020-11-12&utm_source=google&utm_medium=smart_campaign&gclid=Cj0KCQiA2sqOBhCGARIsAPuPK0joxfq3ybVjgJF6ojcl2qUQidhbRtrNWK8kh8-XJbqIDmgasCvOZ8EaAvXZEALw_wcB

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya!

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I am looking more for resources that focus exclusively on Mishnaic Hebrew. The other sources are more for Gemara and Aramaic.